# Keycloak SSO user not get logout, even after clicking on logout

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

I am using the Keycloak for SSO. Keycloak login is working but the issue is that when I click on logout and UI is showing the Login page, but when I select the keycloak login and it is getting logged in with the previous user.

Comment: Which keycloak version are you using

Comment: `jboss/keycloak:9.0.0` m using this image in my docker-compose